# How many elements in this group - Q8?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How many elements are there in $Q_8=[x,y ; x^4=1, x^2=y^2, xy=yx^3]$

Am I right in thinking this contains the elements: $x,x^2,x^3,y,y^2,y^3,yx,y^2x,y^3x,yx^2,yx^3,y^2x^2,y^2x^3,y^3x^2$ ?

Comment: Note that your list already has some duplication: $x^2 = y^2$.

Comment: The notation $Q_8$ hints at $8$ elements...

Comment: There is a clue to the answer to your question in the name of the group.

Comment: Thank you, so rectifying my mistake we have left $x,x^2,x^3,y,y^3,yx,yx^2,yx^3 $ which gives us 8 elements

Comment: $yx^2 = yy^2 = y^3$. And you forgot $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Bigl\{e, \,x, \, x^2, \, x^3, \, y, \, yx, \, yx^2, \, yx^3\Bigr\}$$
since $y^2x=x^3,\quad y^2x^2=e,\quad y^3x=yx^3,\quad y^3x^2=y,\quad y^3x^3=yx$.

Answer (score 0):

$1,x,x^2,x^3,y,yx,yx^2,yx^3 $ which gives us 8 elements

Comment: You only have $7$: $yx^2=y^3$.